# Assume A and B are compact sets, then there exists $a_0\in A$ and $b_0\in B$ such that $\inf\{d(a,b): a\in A b\in B\}=d(a_0, b_0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Assume $A$ and $B$ are compact sets, then there exists $a_0\in A$ and $b_0\in B$ such that $\inf\{d(a,b): a\in A, b\in B\}=d(a_0, b_0)$. If $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint then certainly $a_0$ and $b_0$ may not be unique. But what if they are disjoint compact subsets? Would the uniqueness hold? Any counter example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sets
$$
\{(0,y) \mid y\in[0,1]\}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\{(1,y) \mid y\in[0,1]\}
$$
in $\mathbb{R}^2$.